# git pull bringing extra level in django project

Tags: python, django, git, github

I have a django project in which the project is called projectname, and the inner base directory is also called projectname.  This is the norm for django projects.  When I run git pull to the server after making changes in my development instance, git inserts the whole top level into that inner projectname directory.  Here is a picture before running git pull:

```
projectname - 
   -app1
   -app2
   -app3
   -static
   -templates
   -projectname
     -settings.py
     -urls.py
     -wsgi.py
     -views.py
```

After I run git pull to bring in changes (git pull https://github.com/user/remoterepo), I have this:

```
projectname - 
   -app1
   -app2
   -app3
   -static
   -templates
   -projectname
     -settings.py
     -urls.py
     -wsgi.py
     -views.py
     projectname - 
       -app1
       -app2
       -app3
       -static
       -templates
       -projectname
         -settings.py
         -urls.py
         -wsgi.py
         -views.py
```

You can see, it has pulled the whole project into the subdirectory.  I am running pull in the top directory, not in the subdirectory.

In the repository, it looks like the first example, as the project should look, and as it looks in the repository and on my development machine.  Why does the git pull process do an extra iteration and bring the whole project into the subdirectory?  I have not seen this particular problem in my searches for a solution, so I wonder what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: maybe someone makes this change somehow and push to github

Comment: Thanks @Junbang Huang!  I just want to say generally, I never ask a question on stackoverflow until I have really searched for an answer and not found one.  I always clarify and document my questions carefully, so hopefully no one has to waste time asking me for clarification.  And I deeply appreciate the help I get here on stackoverflow!  It has saved me a number of times, and taught me a great deal.  Sometimes it simply answers my question, sometimes it confirms what I thought I understood, and helps me move forward, and sometimes it turns a light on that gets me past my stuck-point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have accidentally cloned the repo inside of an existing repo.

Look for where you have `.git` folders. There should only be one in the root folder of your local repository. It looks like you might have another one in the nested `projectname` folder

Comment: Thanks, @Darren Clark, for this.  I have checked, but there is only one .git folder on my development machine, and only one on the server.  I have deleted the whole project, and done a git init, and then a git clone to get the project back in its correct state.  I should say, when this happens, the changed code is always in the inner code set, and I cannot see any changes at the top level.

Comment: your answer must be correct.  I obliterated the chance to confirm that when I deleted the repository and did a fresh clone from the master respository (which I did before I saw this answer).  But today the pull went well, no extra stuff, and all the changes in the right places.  Thanks again!